# Aura component cannot read property '$getActionDef$' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, aura-attribute

I when I press button, I get a lightning alert popup with an error:

> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem
>   continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID
>   shown here and any other related details.Something has gone wrong.
>   Cannot read property '$getActionDef$' of undefined. Please try again.

Apex:

```
public class AuraCtrl {    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String getFoo() {
        return 'OLOLO';
    }    
}
```

Lightning:

```
<aura:component controller="AuraCtrl" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="barAttr" type="String"/>
    <ui:inputText aura:id="barId" label="Bar input" value="{!v.barAttr}"/>
    <ui:button label="Press for Bar!" press="{!c.doGetBar}"/>
</aura:component>
```

JS Ctrl:

```
({
    doGetBar : function(component, event) {
        var action = component.get("c.getFoo");
        // another code does not matter because all breaks with first line
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MLprIAG

> an @AuraEnabled method has to be static.